# Simple discrete math proof

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, first-order-logic

I've recently starting reading Discrete Mathematical Structure - KBR.
One of the exercises asks the following:

Prove that if $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, that $a|b$ and $b|a$, then
$a=b$.

My solution (direct proof):

$a|b \rightarrow b=k_1 a \\ 
b|a \rightarrow a=k_2 b$

It follows from the above then that:

$
a = k_2(k_1a) \\
\Updownarrow \\
1 = k_1k_2
$

Therefore

$b=k_1 a \Leftrightarrow b=1a \Leftrightarrow b=a$

QED.

Is this considered correct, and is the notation allright?
Thanks!

Comment: Looks utterly valid to me

Comment: But the last step is weird. Just conclude that we have $k_1=k_2=1$ which implies $a=b$

Comment: You have to add the obvious (but crucial) point that in $\mathbb Z^+$ the equation $1=k_1k_2$ holds only for $k_1=k_2=1$.

Comment: An even easier approach is to consider $$a\mid b\implies a\le b$$ $$b\mid a\implies b\le a$$ because $\ a,b\ $ are positive. This implies immediately $\ a=b\ $

Comment: The notation could be simplified by using j and k instead of subscript k's.

Comment: Allright, thanks a lot guys!

Comment: The proof is correct, but there are a few more details that need ironing out. That $a = (k_2 k_1)a$ does imply that $k_2 k_1 = 1$ by cancellation, but only because $a \neq 0$. Further, $k_2 k_1 = 1$ implies $k_1, k_2 = 1$, but only because $a$ and $b$ are positive, so it isn't possible that $b$ is a negative multiple of $a$, or vice versa. Personally, I quite like Peter's proof.

Comment: That's true, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Soo I guess there's multiple ways to go about proving the above question.
The simplest would however be to consider the comment left by Peter in the comments:

$a|b \rightarrow a \leq b \\
b|a \rightarrow b \leq a$

Considering the fact that $a,b$ are both positive it follows that $a=b$.